# Laravel Email Sending : SMTP or Google developer APi?

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, google-api

I was trying to send email from my laravel application where i used google SMTP configuaration in my .env. There is google developer API for sending Email also. Which one is better to use for sending Email `SMTP or Developer API` from Laravel Application?

`Google Developer API (PHP) :` https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php

Answer (score 1):

I think if you just need to send an email the best choice is using SMTP, however, if you need to create and send an email at the same time you'll need to able manage mailbox, manage setting etc that will be the case you need to use the Developer API.

Comment: The reason i was trying to say send through email api, i was sending email through SMTP godaddy server. But email sender delay time is big. sometimes it takes 3 minutes to send email that's why i was trying to send through developer API. may be it'll reduce the time delay.